# Where to put Sub-Page components in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-cli

I used Ionic CLI to create my first Ionic app and the pages and navigation work great, but now I want to add a sub-component to one of my pages. I added a folder under the page, created the component, and added it to my declarations and entryComponents, but I I getting the error:

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/nathanielmay/Code/ionicApp/src/pages/page1/sidebar/sidebar.js'
>   at Error (native)

It seems that the file it not getting converted into a `.js` file.

What is the appropriate way to register sub-page components in Angular2, Ionic2 applications?

Comment: if you provide some code could more easy to help you...

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue, and now I can solve it. You should rewrite this `import`. For example, rewrite `import{xx}` from `xx`; you can see this issue is gone.